# AWS Python IAM API - how to get AWS IAM privileges programmatically?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Is there a way to know if an AWS IAM account has the right privileges to create VPC, EC2, SQS, SNS and CloudTrail?

Given the IAM's access key and security access key, I would like to, programmatically, block it from going further to create VPC, SQS, SNS if the IAM does not have the right privileges.

Is there a AWS Python API that I can do this kind of check?
There is DryRun option for VPC, and EC2.  But there is no such option for SQS, SNS, S3, and CloudTrail APIs.

Could anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides a CLI command for that:

```
aws iam simulate-principal-policy \
--policy-source-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/SomeUser \
--action-names sqs:CreateQueue
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-principal-policy.html

You can use it with Python boto3 package as well:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_principal_policy

As a workaround you can also check if specific Policy is attached to the specific User/Role. In case you have order and good structure in your IAM, for both AWS and Customer Managed Policies it could be as simple as:

```
aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name your SomeUser
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name SomeRole
aws iam list-attached-group-policies --group-name SomeGroup
```